# Save and load the image of a button in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Ok so I i am trying to make the user pick an image from the iphone photos and save that image as an image on a button.
When the user shuts down the app and opens it again I want the user to see his saved image again :)
theButton contains the sender of which button is clicked btw.

I can do the part where the user can put the image as the button image.
I use this line to set the image

```
[theButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now I am wondering how can I access that image of the button? So I can save and load it?

I use this code according to a tutorial but I am stuck with the load part because apparently I do not have to use Imageview because it is only readable :)
My code for that:

```
//SAVE
-(NSString *)pathOfFile{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"myfile.plist"];
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject: tileOne.imageView];
    [array addObject: tileTwo.imageView];
    [array writeToFile:[self pathOfFile] atomically:YES];
}

//LOAD
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *filePath = [self pathOfFile];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        //Here it says read only, what to use then?
        tileOne.imageView = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: It's spelled "iPhone".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of object is tileOne?  If it's a UIButton, you answered your own question, just do:

```
[tileOne setImage:[array objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Given that you have an `UIImage *image;` or something in your header-file, I guess you can use it something like

```
-(void)saveImage
{
    NSString *filePath =[documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.x";
    NSMutableData *dataToSave = [NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:dataToSave];
    [archiver encodeObject:image forKey:@"theImage"]; //if 'image' is I.E an UIImage
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [dataToSave writeToFile filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];//do some additional error-stuff
}
-(void)openImage
{
    NSString *filePath =[documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.x";
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath])
    {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]initWithReadingWithData:data];
        image = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"theImage"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    }
    else
    {
        //No images was previously saved, do something else, image = nil
    }
}
```